# MATLAB if function with &, Matrix dimensions must agree error

Tags: matlab, if-statement

My code works when I type

```
if size(k)==size(k1) 
    disp('They match');
end
```

or

```
if k-k1==0
    disp('They match');
end
```

but if I type in two conditions at the same time like this,

```
if size(k)==size(k1) & k-k1==0
    disp('They match');
end
```

I get an error saying

> Matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> Error in practice (line 32) if size(k)==size(k1) & k-k1==0

FYI, the dimension of `k` and `k1` are both `1x717` double. I checked it.

So I want to make an `if` statement that includes two conditions at the same time, but I am experiencing an error. Two `&&` won't work cuz two `&&` is for scalars, but my `k` and `k1` are vectors.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you compare two vectors the result would be also a vector (a logical vector), but an `if` condition accept scalar logical values, so you can use `all` function.

```
if all(size(k)-size(k1)==0) && all(k-k1==0)
    disp('They match');
end
```

You should always use `&&` in a loop, '&' is used only for logical operation AND.

I have tested this and it works:

```
k = rand(1,10);
k1 = k;

if all(size(k)-size(k1)==0) && all(k-k1==0)
    disp('They match');
end
```

because when you do this:

```
>> k-k1==0

ans =

  1×10 logical array

   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

So the `if` does not know which value to refer to. But when you do

```
>> all(k-k1==0)

ans =

  logical

   1
```

It gives a unique answer for all the elements of the vector.

---

**Important Note:**

Comparing numbers is not a good idea for making decisions on the loops, because of the [Floating Point Error problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab).

**A Better War to Handle it**

If you read about the floating point error problem, you will see that sometimes,
`2.000 == 2.000` results to  `false`. In order to fix that you can do as follows:

```
tolerance = 0.0001;
if all(size(k)-size(k1)==0) && all(abs(k-k1)<=tolerance)
    disp('They match');
end
```

You first define an acceptable tolerance value depending on the nature of the problem you are trying to solve and then instead of comparing the subtract to zero, you compare the absolute value of the abstract to the tolerance. Thus, the numbers such as `23.0001` and `23.000` would be considered equal.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `size(k)` and `size(k1)` returns 1*2 vectors (number of rows and columns), so `size(k)==size(k1)` returns two values. On the other hand `k-k1==0` returns only logical matrix with same dimension as k & k1.

For example, if `k == k1`, you would expect both to be equal.

```
size(k)==size(k1) % returns 1 1
k == k1  % returns 1

if [1 1] && 1 % gives erros
```

Alternatively, use `isequal` which will not give error even if dimensions not matching.

```
isequal(k,k1) % returns 1 if equal, 0 otherwise.
```

Comment: k-k1==0 does not return only one value, it returns a vector of the size of `k`.